# How to display data from an array with foreach() in php?

Tags: php

How to display data from an array with foreach() in php? I would like to do it so it displays in href with one on a new line.

Comment: Bad problem description, bad research...

Comment: this is an associative array or a simple collection? Post some code and sample data.

Comment: I think you have a couple of good answers to help you and work it out from here but I would strongly recommend posting some of your code to let others see what you have tried and failed at doing as it makes it much easier for others to visualise the problem and then provide a hopefully working solution for you.

Answer (score 4):

for this You can use

```
  <?php
     $x=array("one","two","three");
      foreach ($x as $value)
      {
       // echo '<a href="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a><br />';
       echo $value . "<br />";
    //as your requirements..
       }
```

output:

```
       one
     two
    three
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php foreach($yourarray as $array){?>
<a href="#"><?php $array['index'] ?></a>
<?php }?>
```

Do you mean like the above?